# Capturing TextChanged on a text field

Tags: c#, winforms

Not sure what I'm doing wrong since this doesn't work at all. `TextChanged`, `KeyDown` or any function that is listening on a text box.

Can you advise how to create a listener to perform functions XYZ when text is entered on txtSearch textbox?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();  
}

void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmboxCountry.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Comment: Is there a wire-up to these events in the designer.cs file?

Comment: How did you created this method? Was it by designer? Or manually?

Comment: Assign the event in your xaml to the textbox or add it programatically. By just writing this code it isn't bound to anything.

Comment: I've created this manually but I am using windows forms.

Comment: Right well this is mind boggling.. So if I double click on the txt field which has the exact same format what I've written before it does work now.. is it because it creates a wire up in windows forms when I do it through the UI?

Comment: This is because it's adding this line to Form1.Designer.cs class, which is loaded automatically.

Comment: Perfect thank you! Now I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that this method is set to event you are expecting. This line should be added somewhere after `InitialiseComponent()` to be sure that `TextBox` has been already initialised.

```
 txtSearch.TextChanged += txtSearch_TextChanged;
```

You can set it either in a code, or in Designer class. To add this line at designer class, you can use Event tab page at properties window of text box, by double click on Event you like to add.

Answer (score 1):

Have you hooked up the event either in the designer file or somewhere else in code e.g.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();  
    this.txtSearch.TextChanged += txtSearch_TextChanged;
}
```

Comment: fix grammatical or spelling mistakes